# Is multiple mysqld processes for 1 mysql server is normal?

Tags: server, mysql

I'm not an server administrator, but i would like to know why on the server i have like 10 myslq instances?
Is it good or bad?
Does it negatively impact speed of my website?

Here's screenshot:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: They are not quite instances of mysql, but threads.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default MySQL starts more processes ("threads") to improve performance. If you are familiar with Apache, it does the same thing.

If you want to limit the number of threads, you'll want to limit the number of connections. You can use the [max_user_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) variable to do this or with recent versions (5.5+) you can [limit them per user](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-resources.html).

Comment: Will that slow down mysql ?

Comment: Your cpu is more important in that regards. If you got the CPU for it you won't notice it.

Comment: in fact, I'am experiencing this issue but do not have much option to increase CPU anytime soon, users are complaining about the web app being very slow and i suspected it was because of the database, and indeed it is, seeing the CPU at 100% almost all the time... So I was wondering what i could do to improve speed, using the same CPU.